# Germany: Permanent Resident - Spouse visa language requirement

Tags: visa, germany

I'm from India and I got my Niederlassungserlaubnis (Unlimited settlement permit) in Germany this January. I'm getting married in June and my fiancée hasn't enrolled for any German classes so far and from what I have read, a basic German (A1) certificate is necessary if the spouse holds an unlimited settlement permit, whereas it is not mandatory if I hold a Blue Card. I also found a following conditions for exemption in the same document:

***You have a university degree and probably will be able to find work in Germany on the basis of your language skills (recognisably minor need for integration requirement).***

She holds a master degree from India and can she then apply without the A1 certificate? Does anyone here have any experience regarding the same?

[German language exemption](http://www.india.diplo.de/contentblob/3265640/Daten/3846113/deutsch.pdf)

Comment: I also had a similar question about language test before https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/11439/which-german-language-test-would-be-more-recognized-as-demonstrating-command-of and it seems to depend a lot on the local authority. Better go and ask Bürgeramt directly?

Comment: Your spouse has to take the classes, but she may do this while already in Germany. Failing the test multiple times will require you to go to court – but these cases are rare.

Comment: A1 is a really basic level and can be studied within several weeks if you can afford an intensive language course (3-6 hours every day). Since she is going to move to Germany, it can be anyhow a good idea to do such a course. So my advice would be to just do a course.